# mongobd где храниться бд?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

сама mongobd находиться в C:\ но не в одной из папок найти бд не смог. (ведь как я понял, монга хранить данные в виде файлов)

Comment: У меня это в папке `data` с установленной Mongo, рядом с `bin и log`. Там даже файлы есть с названиями `collection-???` и `index-???`

Comment: да, должно быть так, но у меня видимо все через ()*() , хз что делать, куда в общем он сохраняет бд.

Comment: но я правда самостоятельно путь для установки выбирал. А если по дефолту, может как и другие проги где-нибудь в недрах по пути к пользовательской папке.

Comment: Настройки глянуть видимо не судьба? Собсно в настройках указано где и как хранить БД :)